# Bower: Unable to find a suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower, momentjs, bower-install

thanks for your time.

I am having this issue "Unable to find a suitable version for angular" and I don't know what to do because I get many options, if you were in my shoes what would you do in this case??

This is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "365HW",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.x",
    "bootstrap": "~3.x",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.0",
    "bootstrap-validator": "~0.9.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "latest",
    "angular-animate": "latest",
    "jquery": "~2.1.x",
    "angular-messages": "latest",
    "angular-ui-validate": "latest",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.2.3",
    "moment": "~2.11",
    "angular-moment": "1.x.x"
  }
}
```

C:\wamp\www\365HW>bower install

```
bower angular-resource#~1.4.0   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.4.9
bower angular-resource#~1.4.0 validate 1.4.9 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#~1.4.0
bower angular#~1.4.x            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.9
bower angular#~1.4.x          validate 1.4.9 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.4.x
bower bootstrap#~3.x            cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower bootstrap#~3.x          validate 3.3.6 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.x
bower angular-sanitize#~1.4.0   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.4.9
bower angular-sanitize#~1.4.0 validate 1.4.9 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#~1.4.0
bower angular-cookies#~1.4.0    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.4.9
bower angular-cookies#~1.4.0  validate 1.4.9 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#~1.4.0
bower angular-route#~1.4.0      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.4.9
bower angular-route#~1.4.0    validate 1.4.9 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#~1.4.0
bower bootstrap-validator#~0.9.0           cached git://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator.git#0.9.0
bower bootstrap-validator#~0.9.0         validate 0.9.0 against git://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator.git#~0.9.0
bower moment#~2.11                         cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.11.2
bower moment#~2.11                       validate 2.11.2 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.11
bower angular-moment#1.x.x                 cached git://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#1.0.0-beta.4
bower angular-moment#1.x.x               validate 1.0.0-beta.4 against git://github.com/urish/angular-moment.git#1.x.x
bower angular-ui-validate#*                cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate.git#1.2.2
bower angular-ui-validate#*              validate 1.2.2 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate.git#*
bower angular-bootstrap#*                  cached git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#1.2.2
bower angular-bootstrap#*                validate 1.2.2 against git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
bower angular-local-storage#~0.2.3         cached git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git#0.2.5
bower angular-local-storage#~0.2.3       validate 0.2.5 against git://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.git#~0.2.3
bower angular-messages#*                   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#1.5.0
bower angular-messages#*                 validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-messages.git#*
bower angular-animate#*                    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.5.0
bower angular-animate#*                  validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#*
bower jquery#~2.1.x                        cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#~2.1.x                      validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#~2.1.x
bower jquery#>= 1.8.3                      cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.1
bower jquery#>= 1.8.3                    validate 2.2.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#>= 1.8.3
bower jquery#1.9.1 - 2                     cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.1
bower jquery#1.9.1 - 2                   validate 2.2.1 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 2
bower angular-bootstrap#*                     new version for git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
bower angular-bootstrap#*                 resolve git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#*
bower angular-bootstrap#*                download https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/archive/1.2.4.tar.gz
bower angular#1.5.0                        cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower angular#1.5.0                      validate 1.5.0 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.5.0
bower angular-bootstrap#*                 extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-bootstrap#*                resolved git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower.git#1.2.4

Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.4.9 which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-cookies#1.4.9, angular-resource#1.4.9, angular-route#1.4.9, angular-
sanitize#1.4.9
    2) angular#~1.4.x which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by 365HW
    3) angular#>=1.2.0 <1.6.0 which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-moment#1.0.0-beta.4
    4) angular#^1.x which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-local-storage#0.2.5
    5) angular#>= 1.3.0 which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-ui-validate#1.2.2
    6) angular#>=1.4.0 which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-bootstrap#1.2.4
    7) angular#1.5.0 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-animate#1.5.0, angular-messages#1.5.0

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just choose one and go on, you have specified version `1.4.x` but there is few that fits that query so you are asked to select one.

Comment: And remember to put ! before choosing the number so your bower.json file is updated accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Any answer would be ok, just write `!1` and everything will still working ok.